# Hovering over window switches focus to it on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

When I cross the border of a smaller foreground window by even 1 pixel it immediately changes focus to the larger background window without even clicking on it. How do I turn this off?

I'm running on Windows 8.1. This happens on all programas

Comment: Which operating system are you experiencing this problem with? Which programs? What have you tried?

Comment: refer to this http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/switch-windows-by-hovering-the-mouse-over-a-window-in-windows-vista/  Or Search for "Switch Windows by Hovering the Mouse Over a Window in Windows 7 or Vista"

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Control Panel > Ease of Access Center.
2. Click on *Make the mouse easier to use*.
3. Scroll to *Make it easier to manage windows*.
4. Uncheck *Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse* and OK your way out.

[image: 1]